# Inherit custom TabBar and implementation of resizeEvent

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtabbar, eventfilter

I'm inserting and removing tabs dynamically via QSpinBox which works fine. To fill the whole width of the screen (800px) I need to expand the tabs using my own eventFilter:

**mainwindow.h**

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class CustomTabBar : public QTabBar
{
public:
    CustomTabBar(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR)
        : QTabBar(parent)
    {
    }

    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        /* Resize handler */
                if (e->type() == QEvent::Resize) {
                    // The width of each tab is the width of the tab widget / # of tabs.
                    resize(size().width()/count(), size().height());
                }
    }

    void tabInserted(int index) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        /* New tab handler */
        insertTab(count(), QIcon(QString("")), QString::number(index));
    }

    void tabRemoved(int index) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        /* Tab removed handler */
        removeTab(count() - index);
    }
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    CustomTabBar *tabs;
};
```

The relevant code of my mainwindow looks as follows:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    cells = new CustomTabBar(this);
    cells->tabInserted(1);
//    cells->installEventFilter(resizeEvent());
}

void MainWindow::changeCells(int value)   // Called when QSpinBox is changed
{
    if (cells->count() < value) {
        cells->tabInserted(1);
    }
    else if (cells->count() > value) {
        cells->tabRemoved(1);
    }
}
```

As said the maximum width is set to 800 pixels. The desired behaviour would be:

- One tab: 800px width
- Two tabs: 400px width each
- ...

But it's segfaulting whereever I'm using one of these custom events.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the segfault?

Comment: Well yes.. in my example-code above it's faulting at the first `cells->tabInserted(1);` line. If I'm commenting it out it's faulting in the mainwindow.h customTabBar class. Apparently I'm not able to find what or where I'm missing something.. :)

Comment: You appear to be calling resize from within the resizeEvent override which will a) resize the tab bar itself rather than individual tabs and b) lead to infinite recursion and, probably, a segfault.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I see but how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Is setExpanding(true) what you're looking for?  From the documentation ``This property holds when expanding is true QTabBar will expand the tabs to use the empty space.''

Comment: `setExpanding` didn't help me at all since it's only expanding the tabs (kind of) half of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from the comments I tried to override the tabSizeHint member of QTabBar and `it works for me'...

```
class tab_bar: public QTabBar {
protected:
  virtual QSize tabSizeHint (int index) const override
  {
    QSize s(QTabBar::tabSizeHint(index));
    s.setWidth(width() / count());
    return(s);
  }
};
```

It appears to work as you require -- the tabs sized to occupy the full window width.

Note that there may also be other style factors that affect this but I haven't had time to check.

Comment: Thank you so much G.M.! That did the trick with a few modifications. Sadly I can't upvote yet.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to `disconnect(this, SIGNAL(resize()), this, SLOT(resizeEvent())`, *then* re-`connect([...])` after you've called `resize()`, to avoid a stack overflow caused by an infinite recursion of resize -> resizeEvent. Edit: just like @G.M. says.

```
void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
{
    disconnect(this, SIGNAL(resize()), this, SLOT(resizeEvent());

    /* Resize handler */
    if (e->type() == QEvent::Resize) {
        // The width of each tab is the width of the tab widget / # of tabs.
        resize(size().width()/count(), size().height());
    }

    connect(this, SIGNAL(resize()), this, SLOT(resizeEvent());
}
```

With proper design thought, workarounds like this could be avoided, but to give a more helpful suggestion, we'd need to understand your use case better.

Comment: That's what `QObject::blockSignals(bool)` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Since this post is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697666/expand-qtabbar-dynamically) I can see that you did not understand how inheritance works.

`resizeEvent`, `tabInserted` and `tabRemoved` are called from the Qt framework and **should not be called directly**, hence the `protected`. That is what `insertTab` and `removeTab` are for.

What you are doing is, is calling `tabInserted`, which calls `insertTab`, which calls `tabInserted`, which calls `insertTab`, which....

What you want to do is implement a tab resize in your `tabInserted` and `tabRemoved`, just like you (sort of wrongly) did in `resizeEvent`.

```
if (e->type() == QEvent::Resize)
```

Is always true in `resizeEvent`, as that is the condition for Qt to call it.

Comment: Inheritance and I aren't friends yet, that's so true. I took your advice and tried to keep the `tabInserted, tabRemoved, resizeEvent` protected but whatever I did I received the error 'virtual void CustomTabBar::tabInserted/whatever' is protected.. I'm completely lost on that one to be honest..

Comment: Protected means that you can't call it from outside the class, for good reason. Usually you to this for implementation purposes that might differ, based on the derived class, as is happening here. There is almost always a way to trigger the protected method via a public method, like `insertTab` or `removeTab` in this scenario. I would really suggest to read up on C++ inheritance and Qt before continuing.

Comment: Well I know the difference between `public, private or protected`. Read about inheritance as well and thought I got the idea but apparently I didn't and that's why I'm looking for help in that case. Anyways, I was using `cells->insertTab(...)` in my mainwindow.cpp before but as soon as `tabInserted` was protected I got the error message stated above.

Comment: Did it say on what line you tried to call the protected function? You might have forgotten to change one, as I see you call it on 2 locations.

Comment: My bad. Forgot to correct it on the second line. But I'm still missing something since it's not working anyways.. need to look that up I guess. Thank you for your effort anyway!!